# format number from json javascript

Tags: javascript, json, date, format

Hi i use function to get all data from `json` with different formating of date ??

now its `YYYY-MM-DD` how to doit to be `DD-MM` thx so much

```
var jsonData =   
{
    "month": {
        "day": [
            {
                "type": 1405,
                "date": "2017-10-23"
            },
            {
                "type": 1405,
                "date": "2017-10-24"
            },
            {
                "type": 1405,
                "date": "2017-10-25"
            }
        ]
    }
}
dataType=[];

$.each(jsonData.month.day, function (index, value) {
    dataType.push(value.type);
    dataDate.push(value.date);
});
```

Comment: I wonder https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=format+date+%5Bjavascript%5D 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `split()` to split up the string.

```
$.each(jsonData.month.day, function (index, value) {
    dataType.push(value.type);
    var dateFields = value.date.split('-');
    dataDate.push(dateFields[2] + '-' + dateFields[1]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you have to iterate on the array jsondata.month.day. I won't loop in my example

```
x=jsonData.month.day[0].split("-")
newdate=x[2] + "-" x[1]
```

or you can parsing your string date and get day and month.

```
x= Date.parser(jsonData.month.date[0], "YYYY-MM-DD")
day=x.getDate()
month=x.getMonth()+1
newdate=day+ "-" +month
```

Comment: When did the javascript parser start accepting a parse format? Best tell the standard authors, they seem to have [*left it out*](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-date-constructor). ;-)

Comment: @RobG is right! Tks for the advice and sorry for the mistake